# Rearrange cells in a column to a different column with same heading (Excel 2002)

Tags: windows-xp, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2002

I need the values in one column to be rearranged for each set into another column.

[This picture will help explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHhhx.png):

[image: cats are awesome!]

Follow the red lines, that is where I want my data to go.

This shouldn't be too difficult as they all have the same name for the column and heading. I am using Microsoft Excel 2002 and Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Pivot Table feature of Excel. Just follow the instructions given on this [Microsoft Office Excel Help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx).